# Eulerian polynomials of the second kind with \genfrac?

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

The Eulerian polynomials of the second kind are defined as (see for  [example here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45756/expressions-involving-eulerian-numbers-of-the-second-kind-trying-to-show-sum))

```
E_n(x) = \sum_{m\ge0} \left\langle\!\!\left\langle n\atop  m\right\rangle\!\!\right\rangle  x^m .
```

I would like to use `\genfrac` to display this formula (similar as `\genfrac` is used to display the [Eulerian numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135732/reduce-space-between-genfrac-and-indices/135741#135741)). Is this possible?

Comment: Please show us, what you have tried and what your result should look like (screen-shot). What is the problem with the `\genfrac` command from [egregs answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135744) here?

Comment: Related: [How to write Stirling numbers of the second kind?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86056/5764)

Answer (score 3):

The following example takes the double brackets from package `MnSymbol` and uses `\genfrac`. An alternative would be a simple `matrix` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{MnSymbol}{}{%
  \DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsMn}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}
  \SetSymbolFont{largesymbolsMn}{bold}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}
  \DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{
      <-6>  MnSymbolE5
     <6-7>  MnSymbolE6
     <7-8>  MnSymbolE7
     <8-9>  MnSymbolE8
     <9-10> MnSymbolE9
    <10-12> MnSymbolE10
    <12->   MnSymbolE12}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}{
      <-6>  MnSymbolE-Bold5
     <6-7>  MnSymbolE-Bold6
     <7-8>  MnSymbolE-Bold7
     <8-9>  MnSymbolE-Bold8
     <9-10> MnSymbolE-Bold9
    <10-12> MnSymbolE-Bold10
    <12->   MnSymbolE-Bold12}{}
  \DeclareMathDelimiter{\llangle}{\mathopen}{largesymbolsMn}{'164}
                                            {largesymbolsMn}{'164}
  \DeclareMathDelimiter{\rrangle}{\mathclose}{largesymbolsMn}{'171}
                                            {largesymbolsMn}{'171}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\Eulerian}[2]{%
  \mathinner{%
    \genfrac\llangle\rrangle{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\[
  E_n(x) = \sum_{m\ge0} \Eulerian{n}{m} x^m
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses \genfrac although not exclusively; however it does avoid \atop and works with MathJax.

```
\[
\sum_{m\ge0}\left\langle\!\!\!\genfrac<>{0pt}{}{n}{m}\!\!\!\right\rangle x^{m} 
\]
```